# How to get a new value in angucomplete-alt

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angucomplete-alt to fetch remote data in html page that is working properly.
My code is

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angucomplete-alt/3.0.0/angucomplete-alt.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div angucomplete-alt placeholder="College or School" 
    pause="500" 
    selected-object="ed.f" 
    id="clgName" 
    remote-url="get-work?name=" 
    remote-url-request-formatter="remoteUrlRequestFn"
    remote-url-data-field="atomList" 
    title-field="fname" 
    minlength="3"
    maxLength="30"
    input-class="form-control form-control-small" 
    match-class="highlight" 
    input-name="schName">
</div>

{{ed}}
```

This code is working properly on providing name I am getting fname list and on click i am getting this data on {{ed}}

```
{"f":{"title":"sdfsdf","description":
{"fname":"sdfsdf","id":2438},"image":"","originalObject": 
{"fname":"sdfsdf","id":2438}}}
```

In controller I am accessing this value using

```
 console.log(ed.f.originalObject.fname);
```

This is working perfectly for me.
My problem is  if I enter some new text which in not in  suggestion list That text is not accessible in controller.

How to access it?

Comment: Try Using ng-model with the input..

Comment: tried not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the event input-changed as follows,

```
input-changed="inputChanged"
```

and access the changes here,

```
$scope.inputChanged = function(str) {
      console.log(str);
}
```

Comment: Working Properly